# Bluetooth icon stays white?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I am working on an iOS app which uses Core Bluetooth. When the app gets SIGKILL-ed, the Bluetooth icon on one device stays white, even though it isn't connected to anything. When I next run the app, that device has problems connecting to the other device.

How do I "refresh" the connections? Or is there a way to cancel connections before the SIGKILL?

(The devices have to stay connected even when the app is in the background)

Answer (score 1):

As an experiment you can try to retrieve the connected devices with the `retrieveConnectedPeripherals` method. If the device you are trying to connect is in the connected list, then it may be possible to start using it again.

Also, try to forcefully disconnect the other device by removing the battery or turning it off. If the connection stays there, then this is definitely a bug.

This is most probably an iOS bug or some optimization that is implemented only for handling connections between i* devices. I don't know of others having this issue, neither did I stumbled upon it but in these cases it is best to report it to Apple at the same time with as much info as you can provide (https://bugreport.apple.com/) You should try with newer iOS versions as well to see if it still exists.

Comment: When I turn Bluetooth on then off again, the icon is grey. I'll try your experiment and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: I saw your ADF post but didn't have any more ideas.

Comment: Apple Developer Forums :)